# Pytest Scoping Issue with Fixture Indirect

Tags: pytest

I have the following:

// `conftest.py`

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def deviceundertest(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setupteardown(deviceundertest):
    yield "conn"


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def data1(setupteardown):
    return response


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def data2(setupteardown):
    return response
```

// `test_000.py`

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("deviceundertest", ["server1", "server2"], indirect=True)
def test1(data1):
    assert True

@pytest.mark.parametrize("deviceundertest", ["server3", "server4"], indirect=True)
def test2(data2):
    assert True
```

// `test_001.py`

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("deviceundertest", ["server1", "server2"], indirect=True)
def test3(data1):
    assert True


@pytest.mark.parametrize("deviceundertest", ["server3", "server4"], indirect=True)
def test4(data2):
    assert True
```

When I run a `--setup-plan` and look at one of the fixtures Im seeing the fixtures setup and teardown is being performed more then its actual scoop (i.e session). Example below:

```
❯ pytest example_dir --setup-plan | grep "SETUP    S deviceundertest"
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server1']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server3']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server1']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server3']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server2']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server4']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server2']
SETUP    S deviceundertest['server4']
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytest doesn't check if the arguments are the same in multiple tests, every test is independent. The `scope="session"` is relevant only if the `fixture` is not invoked explicitly, which you are doing, so every parameter in each test will invoke the `deviceundertest` `fixture`.

You can implement a simple logic in `conftest.py` to use the same server instance in multiple tests

```
servers = {}

@pytest.fixture
def deviceundertest(request):
    server = request.param
    if server not in servers:
        servers[server] = Server() # create your server instance
    return servers[server]
```

Comment: Thanks. When you say "invoked explicitly" do you mean via a test parametrization or just being passed to a test function directly? 
The other point is. If I remove the session scope from `deviceundertest` then I get a `ScopeMismatch` due to the other fixtures. If Im reading this right (feel free to correct), the fixtures `data1`, `data2` and `setupteardown` will be session scoped as they ARE directly called via the test parametrization. Even though I need to place a session scope onto `deviceundertest` it WILL NOT be honoured. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @felix001 by "invoked explicitly" I mean you are invoking `deviceundertest` via `parametrize`, even if it's `indirect`. Regarding the `scope="session"` all the fixture should have the same scope, but since they are invoked every time you can simply remove it from all the fixtures, but it's not important, it won't effect anything.

Comment: Thanks. However it looks like the fixture that is directly called doesn't honor scope but  the other fixtures still do. From what I can see it if I leave the scope in place for session on all other fixtures then I get the fixtures scoping correctly (session) for anything that is NOT directly called (i.e via the test parameterize.

Comment: @felix001 That's true, if the `fixture` is not called explicitly the scope is honored. However in the example you posted `deviceundertest` and `data*` fixtures are called by the tests and `setupteardown` is invoked by the `data*` fixtures.

Answer (score -1):

You are sending different params to the root fixture through "@pytest.mark.parametrize", so it's creating a different fixture each time with the value you sent.
A fixture doesn't repeat the setup/teardown process only if it will 100% return the same value, in you case each time a different value can be menifested.

Comment: Hmm not sure on that as the paramus are the same. Ie server1 and server2 are the same for test1 and test3.

Comment: Even if they are the same, they can theorically can be different and pytest doesn't check for the values in the contex of fixtures when using paramtrize, if you want to use the same fixture setup/teardown then think of using scope="class" for those cases or alterntivelly use different fixtures with the strings values already inside