# using parametrized fixtures in pytest

Tags: pytest

I need to write several tests that use a resource (server) with different configurations.
The thing is that I do not need to cover the cross product of all the parameters. Instead i need to make sure test `A` checks something with its own configuration, and test `B` will check something with its own config (see below).

How do I use pytest idiomatically to achieve this? Ideally, I would like to annotate my tests with `config=(flag='a')` etc and this would somehow create an unique fixture with these parameters.

```py
    
    @pytest.fixture
    def server_a():
        return Server(flag='a')

    @pytest.fixture
    def server_b():
        return Server(flag='b')

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_a(server_a):
        return Client(server_a)

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_b(server_b):
        return Client(server_b)

    
    def test1(client_a):
        pass
    
    def test2(client_b):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytest's [indirect fixture parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments) should work for you.

Here is a code example based on the official documentation - it has a nice syntax as well:

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def x(request):
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, y", [("a", "b")], indirect=["x"])
def test_indirect(x, y):
    assert x == "aaa"
    assert y == "b"
```

Comment: Thanks @peter-k. Do you know if it's possible to do with scope that is not function?
My server resource is a bit expensive and I would like to reuse it between runs.

Comment: Indirect parametrization might mess up scoping. See the workaround suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72589590/3800552